# Continuously monitor physical device disconnection throughout runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have an application that has multiple devices connected with different communication protocol, including various serial ports, USB, wired TCP/IP, and even wireless (Zigbee, Bluetooth, WIFI etc.). Due to hardware issues and limited API of certain devices, not all devices have the capability to report or signal "disconnection" to the software layer when it is physically disconnected or out of battery.

My work around is to create a loop on a separate thread that runs at starting of the application and throughout the runtime of the application up to 48 hours without restarting the application. This thread continuously checks if all device feedback a signal, and if not, consider it disconnected and update my GUI.

What is the best way that is robust and take the minimal resources (memory)

1. Raise a **Dispatch.Invoke** then create an infinite loop that constantly check feedback signal
2. Use a **BackgroundWorker** thread. I have only used it for progress bar, and am not sure if it is designed for such purpose running in extended time.
3. Or is there a better/standard way to do such job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to check current device status. And [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416(v=vs.110).aspx) to update UI

Comment: I have tried that and per 2 hours I check in task manager there is an increase of 10MB in memory usage. So I would expect running for 48hours will result in 240MB increase in memory usage.

Comment: @KMC there can be issue with your implementation. You can use any preferred memory profiler or create new question with code and your observations